# I cannot apply CSS through Jquery on the content which is getting loaded dynamically.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

There is an anchor tag, when you click that a qtip appears. That qtip is dynamically generated.

```
<a class="change-zip" href="#zip-change-tooltip">something</a>
```

/*this is dynamically loaded */

```
<div class="qtip">
 <div class="content">
   <div id="zip-change-tooltip">
     *content is here*
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Now on above content i am using this

```
$(document.body).on('click','.change-zip',function(){

        $('#zip-change-tooltip').parents('.qtip').css('height','200px');
});
```

It doesn't work in the first place but when i click on it second time it works fine that's because the DOM is already loaded. What should i do to make it work ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to define how the code is *dynamically* loaded and when.  What are the conditions that cause it to be placed into the DOM?

Comment: jsp is responsible for the dynamic content loading and the qtip loads when the anchor tag is clicked. And i want to manipulate things using jquery only.

Comment: Simple solutions if possible

1. You must call $('#zip-change-tooltip').parents('.qtip').css('height','200px'); after the content dynamically loaded (in success function of AJAX call)

2. You can pass the height to page eg: dynamic.php?height=200px 
and apply that height in the markup <div class="qtip" style="height:200px;">

Comment: You have to think about the scope of what you are 'querying.' Think of the outside parent of where the dynamic stuff goes, and then draw up an event based on that. `$('.div-outside-dynamic-stuff).on("click", ".change-zip", function()...`  - this watches that scope, and waits for interaction with `.change-zip` within. Not sure what `parent()` is really for... can't you just target what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in jquery called

```
$(document.body)
```

You will get an error in that.. just use

```
$(document)
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// your code here after document is ready
});
```

or use

```
$(document).on('click','.change-zip',function(){

        $('#zip-change-tooltip').parent().parent().css('height','200px');
});
```

Comment: it still didn't work, it just works the second time. When the qtip content is already present in the DOM. When i click the link then the qtip content get's added in the dom.

Comment: in which link? click the link then the qtip content get's added in the dom

Comment: yes, when the link is clicked. The qtip content is added in the dom .

Comment: I meant .change-zip link or another one??

Comment: when i click the anchor tag having class change-zip then the <div class="qtip"> is added dynamically in the dom.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what you're seeing a styling issue, I dropped your code into JSBin and it works:
http://jsbin.com/tumogaxahi/1/

If you edit that JS bin, this is the code that's being used. It's basically identical to what you provided with some basic CSS so you can see the height change. I'm appending the change zip anchor tag after adding the click handler to demonstrate that the delegated handler is working.

```
<style>
.qtip {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
}

.change-zip {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

</style>

<div class="qtip">
 <div class="content">
   <div id="zip-change-tooltip">

   </div>
 </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document.body).on('click', '.change-zip', function() {
    $('#zip-change-tooltip').parents('.qtip').css('height','200px');
});

$('#zip-change-tooltip').html('<a class="change-zip" href="#zip-change-tooltip">something</a>');
</script>
```

Have you inspected the qtip in devtools to see if the inline style is being applied? If it is, perhaps there is a CSS rule overriding the inline style -- !important in a CSS rule will override an inline style applied by JS.

Just a side note - $(document.body) is totally valid - it's just creating a jQuery object around the dom node represented by document.body. It's effectively the same as $('body'), but using the native document.body is a faster selector because it doesn't have to use jQuery's selector engine.

Comment: I understand what you are doing over here, but my question was to handle the dynamically loaded qtip content. When i click the anchor tag having class change-zip then the <div class="qtip"> is added dynamically in the dom. Which is having it's own height. But the problem is i want to change the height after it gets loaded in the dom*this happens when the change-zip link is clicked. And for the first time it doesn't work because the content is still loading but when i click the anchor tag second time the qtip height changes as the qtip content is present in the DOM. I hope you get my question.

Comment: I cannot post the actual code here template is just to show how it is working.

Comment: My anchor *is* added dynamically - see the last line of javascript. The behavior you're describing - after loading - indicates there's some async behavior going on here. How is the content being added? Is this ajax or is there some computation going on? Is there additional content besides the new link? I think we need some more info.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it. I basically added setTimeout of 100 on my function so it would be executed after a delay. That would help the DOM to load first and then apply the css on it. Thank you guys for your time.

```
$(document.body).on('click','.change-zip',function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
        $('#zip-change-tooltip').parents('.qtip').css('height','200px');    
        },100);

    });
```

The delay is so short that it's hard to notice the change in the css. It worked like a charm.